# TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a simple script. I'm trying to not use anonymous functions in jQuery, in order to maintain clean the code. This is the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var Call = {
        selection: '',
        init: function() {
            this.product_opt = $('#product_opt');
            this.listenChange();
            //this.test();
        },
        listenChange: function() {
            this.product_opt.live('change', this.afterChange);
        },
        afterChange: function() {
            $("#product_opt :checked").each(function() {
                this.selection = $(this).attr('value');
                console.log( this.selection );
                this.ajax_get_cat();
            });
        },
        ajax_get_cat : function(){
            return $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/mydomain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: {
                    'action': 'show_slider_callback',
                    'selection': this.selection
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    //console.log(data);
                    console.log('returned' + data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    Call.init();
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="product_opt">
    <input id="1" class="selector" type="radio" name="group1" value="6" />  
    <input id="1" class="selector" type="radio" name="group1" value="6" />    </div>
```

When I try to use the form this is the error message returned in console:

> TypeError: this.ajax_get_cat is not a function
>   this.ajax_get_cat();

Comment: `I'm trying to not use anonymous functions in jQuery, in order to manitain clean the code` an odd statement considering that 1) there's nothing wrong with anonymous functions, and they certainly aren't 'unclean' and 2) you've got lots of them in your code. Also note that you're missing the error at the end of the question.

Comment: the issue is `this`, you need to maintain the scope and contexts.

Comment: Thanks. How I can mantain the scope of 'this' ? Thank you very much for both quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is you're using this.ajax_get_cat within your loop where this actually references each element returned in the selector.

You're also making the same mistake when setting this.selection, simply change this to Call and you should be good to go.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var Call = {
        selection: '',
        init: function() {
            this.product_opt = $('#product_opt');
            this.listenChange();
            //this.test();
        },
        listenChange: function() {
            this.product_opt.live('change', this.afterChange);
        },
        afterChange: function() {
            $("#product_opt :checked").each(function() {
                Call.selection = $(this).attr('value');
                console.log( Call.selection );
                Call.ajax_get_cat();
            });
        },
        ajax_get_cat : function(){
            return $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/mydomain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: {
                    'action': 'show_slider_callback',
                    'selection': this.selection
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    //console.log(data);
                    console.log('returned' + data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    Call.init();
});
```

You can also store a proper reference to this before your loop like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var Call = {
        selection: '',
        init: function() {
            this.product_opt = $('#product_opt');
            this.listenChange();
            //this.test();
        },
        listenChange: function() {
            this.product_opt.live('change', this.afterChange);
        },
        afterChange: function() {
            var _this = this;
            $("#product_opt :checked").each(function() {
                _this.selection = $(this).attr('value');
                console.log( _this.selection );
                _this.ajax_get_cat();
            });
        },
        ajax_get_cat : function(){
            return $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/mydomain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: {
                    'action': 'show_slider_callback',
                    'selection': this.selection
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    //console.log(data);
                    console.log('returned' + data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    Call.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change following portion

```
afterChange: function() {
            $("#product_opt :checked").each(function() {
                this.selection = $(this).attr('value');
                console.log( this.selection );
                this.ajax_get_cat(); // this refers to $("#product_opt :checked")
            });
        },
```

to

```
afterChange: function() {
            var self = this;
            $("#product_opt :checked").each(function() {
                this.selection = $(this).attr('value');
                console.log( this.selection );
                self.ajax_get_cat(); //self now refer to Call
            });
        },
```

Comment: All three answers are correct and it seems it solves your problem too. Select one as correct answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `$(...).each` callback, `this` can't be both the current element of iteration (`$(this)...`) and the `Call` object (`this.ajax_get_cat`). It is, in fact, the current object; to access the outer `this`, remember it using the classic `var that = this` before you start `each`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip